# How to set fill alpha in geom_box to number of observation in a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to draw a set of box plots wherein the data is grouped by factors.  I would also like to set the `alpha` value for each box to represent the number of observations in each factor.  The more observations for a given factor, the higher the `alpha`.

Using the `mpg` data as an example...

Drawing the plot is straightforward:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=factor(class), y=displ)) + 
   geom_boxplot(aes(fill="red", alpha=10)) +
   scale_fill_manual(values=c("red"="red"),guide="none") +
   scale_alpha(range=c(0,1), guide="none")
```

[image: Example box plots]

And calculating the number of observations for each `class` is straightforward, using `plyr`:

```
ddply(mpg, .(class), nrow)
       class V1
1    2seater  5
2    compact 47
3    midsize 41
4    minivan 11
5     pickup 33
6 subcompact 35
7        suv 62
```

I am sure there is a clever way to do inside of `ggplot2`, but I have exhausted all ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: Usually, the answer to the question ends up being "shape your data *before* using ggplot."  If you calculate the numbers beforehand and include it as part of your data (i.e. in a column 'freq'), you could use the aesthetic `aes(alpha=freq)` for your boxplot.

Comment: Yeah, was hoping there would be some ggplot2 magic I didn't know about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pull the `alpha` out of the `aesthetic (aes)`, then you can provide the `alpha` value based on `length` of each `class` directly as follows:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=factor(class), y=displ)) + 
      geom_boxplot(aes(fill="red"), 
          alpha = table(mpg$class) / max(table(mpg$class))) +
              scale_fill_manual(values=c("red"="red"), guide = "none")
```

You get this:

[image: ggplot2_alpha]